# Data not loaded using LiipTestFixturesBundle 2.6 and DoctrineFixturesBundle 3.4 in Symfony 6.3.3 with panther 2.1

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fixtures, symfony-panther

I would like to write end to end tests in symfony. Before running the test, I would like to load data into the database using fixtures. The code executes well however, the data is not persisted in the database. I noticed that the indexes of the tables affected by the fixtures have changed.

How do I keep data loaded by fixtures in my test database? Or m'I missing something on how it should work ?

Here is my code :

- An abstract class for all tests :

```
abstract class AbstractWebTestCase extends WebTestCase
{
    use TraitJsonSerializer, PantherTestCaseTrait;

    protected AbstractDatabaseTool $databaseTool;
    protected Client $client;
    protected EntityManager $entityManager;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        self::stopWebServer();
        $this->client = self::createPantherClient();
        $this->databaseTool = static::getContainer()->get(DatabaseToolCollection::class)->get();
        $this->entityManager = static::getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    }
```

- The test that should persist datas :

```
public function testPantherConnexion() : void
    {

        $references = $this->getDatabaseTool()->loadFixtures([
            Fixture::class
        ], true)->getReferenceRepository();

        $this->client->request('GET', '/xxxxx');
        $crawler = $this->client->waitForVisibility('#ktAppBody');
        $this->client->submit(ConnexionForm::CREATE_FORM($crawler));

        $lastInsertedId = $this->entityManager->getRepository(CompteUtilisateur::class)
            ->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->select("MAX(a.id) as maxId")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleResult()['maxId'];



        $compte = $this->entityManager->getRepository(CompteUtilisateur::class)->findOneById($lastInsertedId);

// Trigger an error to stop the panther process and debug the view
// pause() doesn't exist
        $this->client->pause();
    }
```

Here, the $compte inserted by the fixture is present, but when i look into my database using phpMyAdmin, there is none.

- My .env.test file :

```
# define your env variables for the test env here
KERNEL_CLASS='App\Kernel'
APP_SECRET='$ecretf0rt3st'
SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=999999
PANTHER_APP_ENV=test
PANTHER_ERROR_SCREENSHOT_DIR=./var/error-screenshots
DATABASE_URL="pdo_mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/xxxxxxxx?serverVersion=15&charset=utf8mb4"
PANTHER_CHROME_DRIVER_BINARY=%kernel.project_dir%/root/drivers
PANTHER_NO_HEADLESS=1
PANTHER_NO_SANDBOX=1
PANTHER_ERROR_SCREENSHOT_DIR=%kernel.project_dir%/root/var/error-screenshots
```

- dama configuration :

```
#config/packages/test/dama_doctrine_test_bundle.yaml
dama_doctrine_test:
    enable_static_connection: true
    enable_static_meta_data_cache: true
    enable_static_query_cache: true
```

- liip configuration :

```
#config/packages/test/liip_fixtures.yaml
liip_test_fixtures:
  keep_database_and_schema: true
  cache_metadata: true
  cache_db: ~
```

- framework configuration :

```
#config/packages/framework.yaml
# see https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    csrf_protection: true
    http_method_override: false
    profiler:
        only_exceptions: false

    # Enables session support. Note that the session will ONLY be started if you read or write from it.
    # Remove or comment this section to explicitly disable session support.
    session:
        handler_id: null
        cookie_secure: auto
        cookie_samesite: lax
        storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.native

    #esi: true
    #fragments: true
    php_errors:
        log: true

when@test:
    framework:
        test: true
        session:
            storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.mock_file
```

- doctrine configuration

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    #url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    dbname: '%env(resolve:DBNAME)%'
    charset: '%env(resolve:CHARSET)%'
    user: 'root' #'%env(resolve:LOGIN)%'
    password: 'root' #'%env(resolve:PASSWORD)%'
    driver: '%env(resolve:DRIVER)%'
    host: '%env(resolve:HOST)%'
    # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
    # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
    #server_version: '15'
  orm:
    dql:
     string_functions:
      YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
      MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
      DAY: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day
      NOW: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Now
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    enable_lazy_ghost_objects: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
      #      gedmo_translatable:
      #        type: annotation
      #        prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
      #        dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/src/Translatable/Entity"
      #        alias: GedmoTranslatable # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
      #        is_bundle: false
      #      gedmo_translator:
      #        type: annotation
      #        prefix: Gedmo\Translator\Entity
      #        dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/src/Translator/Entity"
      #        alias: GedmoTranslator # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
      #        is_bundle: false
      gedmo_loggable:
        type: attribute
        prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
        dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/src/Loggable/Entity"
        alias: GedmoLoggable # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
        is_bundle: false
      #      gedmo_tree:
      #        type: annotation
      #        prefix: Gedmo\Tree\Entity
      #        dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/src/Tree/Entity"
      #        alias: GedmoTree # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
      #        is_bundle: false
      Entity:
        is_bundle: false
        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
        prefix: 'Entity'
        alias: Entity
      RelationalEntity:
        is_bundle: false
        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/RelationalEntity'
        prefix: 'RelationalEntity'
        alias: RelationalEntity

when@test:
  doctrine:
    dbal:
      # "TEST_TOKEN" is typically set by ParaTest
      dbname_suffix: '_test%env(default::TEST_TOKEN)%'

when@prod:
  doctrine:
    orm:
      auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
      proxy_dir: '%kernel.build_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies'
      query_cache_driver:
        type: pool
        pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
      result_cache_driver:
        type: pool
        pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool

  framework:
    cache:
      pools:
        doctrine.result_cache_pool:
          adapter: cache.app
        doctrine.system_cache_pool:
          adapter: cache.system
```

I tried to insert data in my test database in a panther test case. I expect to find my data into the database DURING the test and eventually after the test but i know that liip purge the database after the test. However, i have inserted by hand some data in the database and they aren't purged at all.

If you need more details, please ask

Thanks in advance for your help :)